# Set android app version from command line

Tags: android, react-native, build, fastlane

I'm trying to set android app version code and name using project variables on running:

```sh
./gradlew bundleRelease -PversionName=1.0.0 -PversionCode=100
```

To use this on my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode project.versionCode
    versionName project.versionName
    [...]
}
```

I remember to use this once, but this time I'm receiving the following weird error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_3d8oq36p9lc2a0ylsa4yduj2n.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_3d8oq36p9lc2a0ylsa4yduj2n$_run_closure1) values: [build_3d8oq36p9lc2a0ylsa4yduj2n$_run_closure1@6e40553b]
```

How can I set the app version code and name with gradle on the command line?

Comment: Did you try this?

`project.versionCode.toInteger()`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Awful error from gradle BTW :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @akif for the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924001/set-android-app-version-from-command-line#comment121828381_68924001)!

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode project.versionCode.toInteger()
    versionName project.versionName
    [...]
}
```